# I keep getting redirected to TWRP after trying to boot to my newly installed LineageOS-16

Tags: rom-flashing, twrp, boot-loop, lineageos, xiaomi

I've been trying to install [LineageOS 17.1](https://www.getdroidtips.com/lineage-os-17-1-redmi-note-8/) on my Xiaomi redmi note 8 for almost a month now, and there is always one obstacle or another. First problem is that while the tutorial websites clearly state their version is made for the redmi note 8, The download page itself always states that the rom is made for the redmi note 8 PRO. In the zip name also  mentions unofficial, while other lineageOS downloads don't mention it. When I'm on the official website, I can't find my phone in the [download page (Xiaomi Redmi note 8)](https://download.lineageos.org/). When I succesfully installed the (unofficial) ROM, I tried to reboot my phone. Instead of entering LineageOS, it reboots into TWRP, even when I reboot it by pressing *system* under *reboot* in the twrp menu. Now, I tried to install [LineageOS 16](https://gearallnews.com/how-to-install-lineage-os-16-on-xiaomi-redmi-note-8-guide/#Steps_to_install_Lineage_OS_16_on_Xiaomi_Redmi_Note_8), but the exact same happens. I always wipe the dalvic cache and cache in between actions. I do have a nandroid backup from MIUI11 in case it just won't work out...
Thanks for being awesome!

I am using:
TWRP 3.4.0-0
I've installed: Magisk 20.4
I've tried installing:
[LineageOS 16 by DarkJoker](https://sourceforge.net/projects/darkjoker360-developements/files/Xiaomi/Redmi%20Note%208/ROM/LineageOS-16.0/lineage-16.0-20200402-DarkJoker360-ginkgo.zip/download) ; [LineageOS 16](https://androidfilehost.com/?fid=4349826312261639609) ; [LineageOS 17.1 UNOFFICIAL](https://androidfilehost.com/?fid=4349826312261768723) ; [LineageOS 17.1 V2](https://androidfilehost.com/?fid=12420606652095399003)
Last time, I tried to flash [vbmeta.img](https://xiaomifirmware.com/download/14341/) first, before flashing the ROM
In all cases, I can't reboot into the system anymore unless I use my restore point.

Comment: Model names can change at any time. The more important info is the code name `ginkgo`. That has to match with your device.

Comment: Hey, I forgot to mention that, the version I've used is made for ginko, and my phone is ginko, the only thing is, that if I understand correctly, the version that's made for my phone, is unified, not made by the original LineageOS makers, but a well-known senior XDA developer with a lot of experience. But it works for a lot of other people out there on the internet. I've found blogs, websites and youtube videos for my phone, all giving me the same download link. I've chosen for LineageOS 16 because 17.1 isn't stable enough for a daily driver.

Comment: consider magisk has bugs. restore MIUI back to working state + follow LineageOS instructions, there it is stated that **formatting** userdata is recommended (you will lose data + sdcard make sure your TWRP backups are copied to PC)